# Covering n points with three squares of minimum length

Tags: algorithm, point

Given a set of `n` points `(a_1, b_1)`, `(a_2, b_2)`, ..., `(a_n, b_n)`. Need to find the minimum `x` such that three `axis parallel` squares each of length `x` together covers all of the points.

I can find the rectangle with smallest area enclosing all the points. Can this rectangle be used somehow? Or any hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe use some sort of clustering algorithm to group the points into three clusters and then cover those individually with one square each?

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is enough to consider two cases:

1. When each square touches some edge of smallest-area rectangle.
2. When two squares are located at opposite corners of smallest-area rectangle while third one lies inside (does not touch any edge of smallest-area rectangle).

In first case we could fix corner of one square at one of 4 rectangle's corners, then fix corners of other two squares somewhere at two opposite (to chosen corner) edges of the rectangle (`n` possible positions for each one), then for each point determine optimal square where it belongs and minimum `x`.

In second case try two opposite pairs of rectangle corners for "outer" squares, then fix one of corners of the "inner" square at all `n*n` positions determined by all `x` and `y` point coordinates, then for each point determine optimal square where it belongs and minimum `x`.

Time complexity would be O(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: Nice.  We can do case 2 in O(n^2) time by first sorting all vertices in increasing order by their minimum distance, under the max norm (i.e. d(x, y) = max(|x1-x2|, |y1-y2|)), to the 2 already-chosen opposite corners.  Then starting with x=0, walk through this list: every point visited increases our tentative x to this new min-dist value (and we conceptually add this point to the corresponding square).  ...

Comment: ... We also maintain the leftmost and rightmost x values, and the topmost and bottommost y values, of all remaining points (these can all be updated in O(1) if we preprocess with 4 more sorting operations).  Stop iterating as soon as max(rightmost-leftmost, topmost-bottommost) <= x, since at this point, we can contain all remaining points with the 3rd square.  (Maybe case 1 can also be sped up with something similar?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: this also works for case 1. And (in both cases) this approach guarantees O(sorting(n)) worst case complexity. Do you consider posting it as separate answer?

Comment: You're right, it's actually faster than I thought :)  I'll write it up as soon as I get time.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this approach to arbitrarily many squares? If `n` is the number of points and `k` the number of squares, doing it in `O(k * n^3)` is the best I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: @G.Bach: which approach do you mean? One in the answer or one in comments? It's pity we don't have separate answer for second one... Anyway, I didn't think about such generalization, most likely both these approaches just don't work with `k>3`. A different generalization is more interesting for me: what if `k` remains small (2 or 3), but points are added sequentially, one after another; what is the best time complexity of finding `x` after each new point?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @EvgenyKluev seems to go in the right direction, but there's a couple of subtleties that I'd like to address.

Since I didn't see a restriction for `x` being integer, you might want to go with binary search on `x` to guide your algorithm, and find suitable terminating conditions when the range still available for `x` is small enough (you would do binary search for integer `x` as well, but there you don't need a terminating condition).

The placement of a square in one corner of the rectangle (something that you will have to do, somewhat straightforward to prove) limits your search space for the placement of the other two squares: let A be the set of points covered by the corner-aligned first square, and let S be the set of all points. Take S-A and find the enclosing rectangle of that set of points. Placing the remaining two squares at opposite corners of the enclosing rectangle of S-A will always be a solution (only one pair of opposite corners might fit), if one exists.

Thus, one algorithm could - very high level - go like this

```
binary search for x on [0,N]:
    find R(S), the enclosing rectangle of S
    for each corner C of R(S):
        align one square at C, let the points covered by that square be A
        find R(S-A)
        do two squares aligned at opposite corners of R(S-A) cover S-A?
```

As for the binary search, I can't really say how fast that will converge to a range that allows only one alignment of squares, at which point you can directly calculate the value `x` - I expect that with arbitrary precision, you can make that arbitrarily bad. Each iteration takes O(n log n) for sorting the points in both cardinal directions.

Comment: This approach is also pretty good. Several comments about binary search: if we sort all x and y coordinates (after subtracting "starting" corner's coordinates) and use the resulting array for binary searches, then only O(log n) search steps are needed. Since all other stuff could be done with at most two linear scans, the whole algorithm's worst case complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Sounds about right. I hadn't properly understood your idea until you clarified how to use it for the binary search, which is why I thought it needed clarification in the first place. Glad I got it now!